# LINQ to extract duplicate data more than 3

Tags: list, linq, nested

```
class Year
{
    public int YearNumber;
    public List<Month> Months = new List<Month>();
}

class Month
{
    public int MonthNumber;
    public List<Day> Days = new List<Day>();
}

class Day
{
    public int DayNumber;
    public string Event;
}
```

So I have a list of Years(`list<year> years`). How do I get the list (another list) which have the result that has duplicates event on the same day? I mean events can be happen on multiple dates, does not matter, what matters is, to find out if this any of date happens the same event from different year. . Lastly, (filter) only if its occurs more than 3 times. Example, 5 July 2014, 5 July 2017 and 5 July 2019 is 'Abc Festival', which occurs more than 3 times. So u get the date, the event, and the number of counts.

Comment: How are events and years connected? Also, showing your own efforts would clarify what you're trying to achieve. Also, why don't you simply use DateTimes?

Comment: this is just an simpler example, the real scenario isn't like this. I've tried group by the day, follow by group by the event where the count more than 3, the first group by is ok, I don't know how to do the second group by on the first group by

Comment: I'm using this example because my problem involves nested list, and I need to check across all the element in list of lists of lists.

Answer (score 1):

Using just the classes you show we can only group dates, where a "date" is a day in a month:

```
var query = from y in years
            from m in y.Months
            from d in m.Days
            select new { m.MonthNumber, d.DayNumber }
            into date
            group date by date
            into dateGroup
            where dateGroup.Count() > 2
            select dateGroup;
            select dateGroup;
```

As you see, the core solution is to build `new { m.MonthNumber, d.DayNumber }` objects and group them.

Comment: how about in lamda expression form?

Comment: The `from - from` construction is the same as `SelectMany` in method syntax (`years.SelectMany(y => y.Months)` etc.). However, query syntax is far better readable. I wouldn't use method syntax if I were you.